# VS Code User Snippet file name manipulation

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

How do I convert my file name `company-controller.js`

To this:

```
class CompanyController extends BaseController {
  constructor() {
    super(Company);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to transform the variable `TM_FILENAME_BASE`

```json
  "ctrl": {
    "scope": "javascript",
    "prefix": "base",
    "body": [
      "class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/} extends BaseController {",
      "\tconstructor() {",
      "\t\tsuper(${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)-\\w+/${1:/pascalcase}/});",
      "\t}",
      "}"
    ],
    "description": "Extend BaseController"
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the second usage of `pascalcase` to `$1:/capitalize}` to avoid confusion.  While `pascalcase` does work here, it is really meant to deal with multiple words with separators between them, which isn't the case in the `super` line.  I just think a new user might be confused why `pascalcase` is  necessary in the second usage.

Comment: @Mark It is needed if the filename is like `company-wood-controller.js`

Comment: Good catch.  `"\t\tsuper(${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*?)-|.*$/${1:/capitalize}/g});"` will also work to strip off whatever is the last part of the filename and capitalize the other parts.